# My site is no longer receiving style React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I've been developing a site as a training for about 1 week now and I was happy with the development, I managed to do a lot already, yesterday I closed the code editor and the hyper terminal to rest and it was working normally without any problem, this morning I opened the site again and decided to refactor some code snippets that were being duplicated at times and it just stopped receiving some styles and attributes from the tags, even after CTRL Z all changes and restarting the server it doesn't go back to normal, when i manually update something in css it goes ok, but it stopped getting sizes in general, like h1 default and bootstrap container-fluid

the site was built with React using the local server, everything installed correctly with npm and imported, I really don't know what the problem is so I'm sorry if I couldn't be exact in the question.

[This is the site before the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0zpa.png)
[This is the site now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etzyf.png)

Note: None of the new elements, navbar etc crash the app, it was working fine and just crashed when i tryed to refactor :(

**Index.html code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Adge Tecnologia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
  crossorigin="anonymous"
/>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>
<script src="../src/index.js" type="text/jsx"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Index.js code**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from "./components/App"

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Not the problem, **but**, you have `bootstrap@5.1.3` defined twice.

Comment: This is a HTML/CSS question and not *React*

Comment: As a suggestion, could it be that bootstrap is overriding your styles as you have styles.css loaded before bootstrap.min.css. Try moving styles.css below bootstrap.min.css and see how you get on.